# re-triggering hook_user_default_permissions?

Tags: hooks, users

I build a module that implements `hook_user_default_permissions` to manage permissions for my site. It's been installed on the site, and its permissions took. But now, a while on, I am making some changes to the permissions, but they aren't taking.

I am trying to figure out how to re-trigger the hook being run. I've tried clearing cache, rebuilding the registry, disabling, uninstalling, and re-installing the module, and rebuilding user perms. None of these have worked. I've looked in the `role_permission` table to verify, and my changes have not been added.

How can I get the hook to run again?

Comment: How/Where did you find out about the existence of this hook? Is it part of some sort of custom module? Because I can't seem to find any reference to it anywhere on drupal.org. Are you sure it actually exists? Because it does sound useful.

Comment: It's part of features, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this hook is a part of features, so I needed to do a `drush fr my_module`.